# modular c++ application design and shm shared memory

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I need to refactor an industrial process application in order to be very easily modular/customisable.

This application will use module/plugins . 
each module contains a func available to drive an unit (imagine it like a 3D printer, I have XY unit , head heating unit, wire feeding unit ...)  . But my application is really bigger than that ...

Each of these plugins must share data resources through shared memory areas in the system (for gui processes )

I would need to find a way to share the data of some classes inside system shared memory areas (POD data).

The challenge is to find a way to implement it in the easiest possible way.
templates, namespaces... or other c++17 features may be welcome.
It may involve complete thinking/refactoring  of the existing application.
At the moment, this means I have some class with a struct containing data :

```
typedef struct mydata {
   int data1;
   float data2;
} T_mydata; 


struct{
   // some data ...
   ...
   // ptr to class struct data 
   T_mydata a_ptr;
   // some other data ...
}
*shmptr;

class A {
T_mydata *data_ptr; // will point *shmptr->a_ptr;
... 
};
```

Comment: Is shared memory a hard requirement ? (and if yes, then why ? - because you are putting yourself down on a more difficult path if so) Also, is the other modules/plugins also in c++ or can they be in some languages ?

Comment: this is a hard realtime automation process , and the modules are too in c++ language. shared memory is a requirement, these data are used for process supervision and  in the non realtime userspace , (eg realtime motor positions, process (modules) states, ....settings modes issued from the userspace interface) ....

Comment: You didn't answer my language question.. and it is really unclear what type of module/plugin you aim at - for instance would drop in .dll work, etc. ??. Im marking to close.

Comment: modules/plugins will be c++ class / methods. in term of solutions may be it will be dll I don't know at the moment.That will depend on the way to implement it.

Comment: It is still very unclear what your issue is. Since you talk about sharing data it sort of implies some multi-threading or multi-processing paradigm.

Comment: I think this may be kind of thing I would need : http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-stl-containers-in-shared-memory/184401639. This is  a Multiprocessing environement , in which you have a driving user interface and an automation process

Answer (score 0):

To implement shared memory, communication, etc. `boost::interprocess` library has utilities for simpel and also fairly complicated concepts.